# Prove $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{a_{n}}=\infty$ for an increasing sequence $a_n$ of positive integers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The $a_n$'s are integers, positive, and increasing: $0< a_1 < a_2 < \cdots$, the problem asks us to prove that:
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{a_{n}}=\infty
$$ 
While I have checked this results for several series like $a_n = n$, $a_n = n^2$, $a_n = n^p$, or $a_n = p^n$ type stuff, I don't know how to prove this general result. A hint is appreciated. Thanks dudes!

Comment: ...and dudettes!

Comment: @tony:do not yet have the privilege of posting a comment, so putting this comment as an answer.Did you try out the sum for the situation when
a(n+1)/a(n) = 1+(1/n^2)?

Comment: Dear Sudhir: in the question, the $a_n$'s are integers.

Comment: Consider a partial sum: $\displaystyle{\large S_{N} \equiv \sum_{n = 1}^{N}{a_{n + 1} - a_{n} \over a_{n}} = \sum_{n = 1}^{N}{a_{n + 1} \over a_{n}} - N > 0}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin And so what? Your comment seems like a misleading hint to me. If it is not, please explain.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I never thought I'd answer a question asked by a superhero! I would advise Mr. Iron Man to use the following well-known theorem:

> Let $\{x_i\}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers. Then the product
>
> $$\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1+x_i)$$
>
> converges if and only if the series
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i$$
>
> converges.

In the present case case, notice that

$$1+\frac{a_{i+1}-a_i}{a_i} = \frac{a_{i+1}}{a_i}$$

so the partial products of the infinite product telescope, to give $a_{n+1}/a_1$, which tends to $+\infty$ by assumption. Therefore, the series $\sum \frac{a_{i+1}-a_i}{a_i}$ diverges.

**Remark** Your series is analogous to the integral $$\int_0^\infty df/f$$ where $f$ is a positive function. Of course, this integral equals $\varinjlim_{x \to \infty} \log (f(x)/f(0))$, which is $+ \infty$ if $f \to \infty$.

Comment: $\dfrac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_n} = \dfrac{\Delta a_n}{a_n}$, so it does look like $\dfrac{df}{f}$, but if I had answered this the answer would not have been so efficient.

Comment: @MichaelHardy What do you mean? Thanks for the edit btw. You were right about the French!

Comment: wow. such nice.

Comment: the integral has to be from $ 1$ to infinity

Comment: @toufik_kh.17 Not if my $f(x)$ is your $f(x-1)$.

Comment: @BrunoJoyal, ok can you please justify the move from $\dfrac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{f(x)}$ to $\dfrac{df}{f}$

Comment: @toufik_kh.17 The analogy here is that the forward difference operator on sequences is analogous to the derivative. It's just an analogy, don't try to read too much into it...

Answer (score 10):

We have $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a_{i+1}-{a_i}}{a_i} \geq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{a_i}^{a_{i+1}}\frac{1}{x}\rm{d}x=\ln\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_1} \right )$$
taking $n\rightarrow \infty$ we get the result.

Comment: The key is that there is a constant $c > 0$ such that $a_{n+1} \ge a_n+c$.